# How to sample from multiple categorical distributions using Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, montecarlo

Let P be an array where each row sums up to 1. How can I generate a matrix A where

- A has the same dimensions as P, and has A_{ij} equal to 1 with probability P_{ij}
- A has exactly one entry equal to 1 in every row, with all other entries zero

How can I do this in Numpy or Scipy?

I can do it using for-loops, but that's obviously slow. Is there a way to use Numpy to make it efficient? Or Numba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows Wikipedia.

```
import numpy.random as rnd
import numpy as np

A_as_numbers = np.argmax(np.log(P) + rnd.gumbel(size=P.shape), axis=1)
A_one_hot = np.eye(P.shape[1])[A_as_numbers].reshape(P.shape)
```

Tested it on:

```
P = np.matrix([[1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4], [1/3,1/3,1/6,1/6]])
```

Got:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score -1):

ok, using choice with 2d expansion

```
import numpy as np

def f(P):
    a = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.int64)
    q = np.random.choice(4, size=1, replace=True, p=P)
    a[q] = 1
    return a

P = np.array([[1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4],
              [1/3,1/3,1/6,1/6]])

r = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, P)
print(r)
```

[[0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]]

[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` is basically a for loop, so this answer is wrong

Comment: explicitly using the number 4 is also wrong